# Windows 10 keeps giving me automatic repair loop even after the clean install?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, clean-install

in the first windows was working perfectly ….. then  I got some kind of green screen of death saying some sort of unknown error … then it got into automatic repair loop  I tried every single fix out there on the internet but all failed …. 
I tried

1- bootrec /fixmbr

2- bootrec /fixboot

but I got  access denied

3- bootrec /rebuildbcd

4- copy the registry files and replace them

5- windows restore point but it failed while trying

6- windows reset but failed after it took long time

7- dism but it failed  too .

8- sfc /scannow  failed   then asked me to try fix the files with dism

[log file](https://justpaste.it/6hx44)

9- dism  from the windows source disk

10- chkdsk /r /f c:  it failed  too

[log file](https://justpaste.it/60hdl)

11- I tried replacing the corrupted file 
but it did nothing

the windows the version  that  I had  while this was the spring creators update 1709... the only fix I had was clean install windows 
I got the rs4 1803 tried installing it but I got windows cannot be installed on this disk the only fix was converting the disk from mbr to gpt 
but  I had no backup disk so  I launched hiren's live cd then partition wizard tool then I clicked convert mbr to gpt  to avoid formatting the disk
then I tried installing  the windows again ant I worked just fine but after 4 days I got through  the same problem that I tried the 10 fixes on it and didn't work ….. then  I clean installed it again after some couple of days  I got the automatic repair loop but I tried system restore point and it worked for the very very first time I was so happy .. then after one day I got the same automatic repair loop  .. and when I tried system restore point again  I found non restore points I clicked reset windows and it worked  !!!!!   but now I  am afraid  to use my pc in case  the error comes again !! although  I tried turning off the automatic repair but I got error 0x000001 while trying to boot !!! I tried  to sort the boot disk from the bios settings but it didn't fix the error !!!!
I scanned the hard drive for bad sectors but  I had non 
[image]
here is some srt log files from the last error I got 
1- [bcdinfo](https://justpaste.it/4bifu)
2-[bootstat.dat](https://www.file-upload.com/bhlxer0re520)
3- [disklayout](https://justpaste.it/4n35f)
4-[DISMRepairLogFile](https://justpaste.it/7d4j4)
5- [SrtTrail.log](https://justpaste.it/5axb6)
6-[SrtTrail.txt](https://justpaste.it/4zbxm)

if i got this error again I would throw my pc at the wall and smash it into pieces and never ever use the bloody error yearning windows again !!!!

Comment: the test again  on all pc parts 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GYaeoUKqEwLdzgYdw3nVSVht1mKMD84r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should make sure you use a clean and healthy Windows 10 ISO image file. Or we need to try to download the image file from Microsoft website and perform a clean installation with USB. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

Comment: Windows 10 ISO image file is not the problem as  i had said " this was the spring creators update 1709"     then i got an win 10 1803 iso r4 ..... and i have already  did a clean installation with USB. ..

Comment: just "never ever use the bloody..." seems like my personal choice. just install Win7 + start work. || else.. can start a clean win7towin10 update straight away..

Comment: the only thing preventing me from doing so is that games needs latest win 10 ver like (forza -State of Decay 2 ...etc )